# incrementing pointers to multi-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *argv[3] = {{"abc"}, {"def"}, {"ghi"}};

    printf("%c\n", (*++argv)[1]); //error. I wanted to print 'b'
    printf("%c\n", *++argv[1]); //prints e

    return 0;
}
```

The error message:

```
error: cannot increment value of type 'char *[3]'
printf("%c\n", (*++argv)[1]);
```

I want to increment `argv` to point to `b`. I took this usage `(*++argv)[i]` straight from C Programming Language by K&R where they have an example on page 117 on incrementing `argv` exactly like I did. They also point out that `(*++argv)[0]` is the pointer to the first character in a string while `*++argv[0]` increments the pointer `argv[0]`. Indeed `(*argv)[1]` will print `b` while `*argv[1]` will print `d`. Yet somehow incrementing `(*++argv)[0]` just keep resulting in error.

Comment: you have an array of pointers, not a pointer to array. and the way `argv` is declared could be different. I guess in k&r it declared as "char**".

Comment: it'll be helpful if you show the error message. in this case you get the error because `argv` is an array and you can not use `++` on it because it's value can not be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this:

```
char *argv[3] = {{"abc"},{"def"},{"ghi"}};
```

Should be this, as noted by others:

```
char *argv[3] = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
```

Second, what you've done is not what the K&R book does.

Array names act like they were constant pointers, so you can't change them like you tried to with that `argv = argv + 1` (expanded version of `++argv`).

But the book does that to an `argv` **passed into main by the command line**, so when `char* argv[]` enters main, it **decays** to a pointer to pointer (`char**`) and then, yes, you could make `(*++argv)[1]` work if you pass the strings as command line arguments.

Try to create a bogus `argv` inside main, like you did, and compare its related addresses with the addresses related to a real `argv` passed into main via command line.

You'll see that one is a `char**` and the other is a `char* array`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{    
    printf("argv:     %p\n", argv);
    printf("&argv[0]: %p\n", &argv[0]);
    printf("&argv:    %p\n\n", &argv);

    char* bogus_argv[] = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
    printf("bogus_argv:     %p\n", bogus_argv);
    printf("&bogus_argv[0]: %p\n", &bogus_argv[0]);
    printf("&bogus_argv:    %p\n\n", &bogus_argv);

    printf("%c\n", (*++argv)[1]);  // prints 'b'
    printf("%c\n", *++argv[1]);    // prints 'e'

    return 0;
}
```

Run: `./program abc def ghi`

**Output on my machine:**

```
argv:     0x7ffcde5aca98
&argv[0]: 0x7ffcde5aca98
&argv:    0x7ffcde5ac9a0

bogus_argv:     0x7ffcde5ac980
&bogus_argv[0]: 0x7ffcde5ac980
&bogus_argv:    0x7ffcde5ac980

b
e
```

Answer (score 2):

The example from K&R refers to `argv` as defined as the second argument to function `main`.  Your definition is different, you define an array of 3 pointers to strings whereas the function argument is a **pointer** to such an array.

The function prototype syntax is somewhat misleading as the same syntax is used for a different type of object. Some people prefer this syntax:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
}
```

With this prototype, the nature of `argv` (a pointer to a pointer to `char`) appears more explicitly, but many programmers prefer the equivalent `char *argv[]` syntax to underline the fact that `argv` points to an **array** of pointers as opposed to a single pointer.

`argv` being an array in your code, you cannot increment it: this explains why you get an error for `printf("%c\n", (*++argv)[1]);`.

You can change your program this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *argument_array[4] = { "abc", "def", "ghi", NULL };
    char **argv = argument_array;

    printf("%c\n", (*++argv)[1]); // will print 'e' instead of 'b'
    printf("%c\n", *++argv[1]);   // prints 'h', not 'e'

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that you should remove the redundant `{}` in the initializer, and the `++` operator is prefix, so the output is not exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

you made a mistake with array your declaration. It should you a warning. It should be

```
char *argv[3] = {"abc","def","ghi"};
```

The inner braces are not neccessary as strings are char pointers and therefore "arrays".

You could declare a second pointer variable and assign it to argv:

```
char ** p;
p = argv;
```

and then increment p.

Last but not least, if you want to print b first and then e, you have to put the "++" operator behind the variable. Otherwise it would increment the pointer before the evaluation and you would print e and h.

Comment: good point with the braces. I re-declared the array still I get the same error.

Comment: what about the other things i mentioned?

Comment: creating p didn't help as well. Regarding incrementing, good point as well, but the main issue persists.

Comment: you also put p in the printf argument instead of argv.

Comment: printf("%c\n", (*p++)[1]);